# android no activity found to handle intent - printershare

Tags: android

i have the following button  in my app, but the app crashes when i press it right now:

```
        Button newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.afronden);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        final Uri printFileUri = Uri.parse("http://ipadress/tablet1.txt");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
        i.setDataAndType(printFileUri,"text/plain");
        i.putExtra( "scaleFitToPage", true );
        startActivity(i);
```

the printershare program is installed, and its name is correct (checked with pm on console).
i read some other posts that i need to add some code to the manifest, but i can't figure out what. Who can help me and show me what code i need to add to my manifest?

Comment: I miss understood what you where trying to do at first. To call an activity from a remote application, you need to assign the category, action (MIME, data type etc... ) of the intent to something that the remote application is expecting. You will need to verify what printershare is demanding to start its activity. Sorry, I can't help you with that.

Comment: i got the code from the printershare website itself: http://www.printershare.com/help-android-integration.sdf  , thats why i don't understand why it gives an error

Comment: I don't know. Double checking you work against that link, it appears that you are doing it correctly. The best I got is maybe the URI can't be an HTTP. Try using a dummy local file and see if that works.

Comment: thanks! seems that was it, entering a local file works without crashes. now i need to be able to download the txt file to the sdcard/download folder :)

Comment: Congratz! Hope all works out well.